# MongoDB BsonDocument Down-Casting

Tags: c#, mongodb, downcast

I have a collection in MongoDB which I'm trying to "FindAndModify" using C# driver.
This collection holds types of a base class and its derived classed, as follows:

```
    [BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
    public class Father
    {
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    }

   public class Son : Father
   {
        public string SomeProperty { get; private set; }
   }
```

When I'm trying to cast the BsonDocument to my base class, after the FindAndModify, where the result is "Son":

```
Father modifiedDocument = result.GetModifiedDocumentAs<Father>();
```

I get the following exception:

> System.IO.FileFormatException: Element 'SomeProperty' does not match
>   any field or property of class Father.

Any idea why? -Can't I perform a down cast here?

Thanks,
Nir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by registering the class map of the "Son" type on load. Here's a reference to the code I'm using:

```
    if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(T)))
    {
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<T>
        (cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers,
Nir.